# How to check if Node already exists neo4j before creating a new one

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am working on an Spring boot + Neo4j application & I am new to graphDb.
Problem I am facing is described below, 
I want to create  unique (Priviledge) node pointing(In relation) to UserRole Node.

In below image you can see duplicate (Priviledge) node is created 
[image]

how can I write a custom cypher to check Priviledge if exist before saving a new one

UserRole Domain:
    @NodeEntity
    public class UserRole {

```
public UserRole(User user, Role role) {
    this.user = user;
    this.role = role;
}

/**
 For Jackson Parsing
 **/
public UserRole() {
}

@GraphId
private Long id;

public UserRole(User user, Role role, Unit unit) {
    this.user = user;
    this.role = role;
    this.unit = unit;
}



public long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Relationship(type = HAS_USERROLE,direction = "OUTGOING")
User user;
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

@Relationship (type = HAS_ROLE_OF,direction = "OUTGOING")
Role role;
public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}


@Relationship(type = "WORKS_IN",direction = "OUTGOING")
Unit unit;

public Unit getUnit() {
    return unit;
}

public void setUnit(Unit unit) {
    this.unit = unit;
}

@Relationship(type = "HAS_PRIVILEDGE", direction = "OUTGOING")
List<Priviledge> priviledgeList;

public List<Priviledge> getPriviledgeList() {
    return priviledgeList;
}

public void setPriviledgeList(List<Priviledge> priviledgeList) {
    this.priviledgeList = priviledgeList;
}
}
```

Priviledge Domain:

```
public class Priviledge {

@GraphId
Long id;


private String priviledge;

private String priviledgeOn;
private Long priviledgeOnId;

public Priviledge() {
}

public Priviledge(String priviledge, String priviledgeOn) {
    this.priviledge = priviledge;
    this.priviledgeOn = priviledgeOn;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPriviledge() {
    return priviledge;
}

public void setPriviledge(String priviledge) {
    this.priviledge = priviledge;
}

public String getPriviledgeOn() {
    return priviledgeOn;
}

public void setPriviledgeOn(String priviledgeOn) {
    this.priviledgeOn = priviledgeOn;
}

public Long getPriviledgeOnId() {
    return priviledgeOnId;
}

  public void setPriviledgeOnId(Long priviledgeOnId) {
    this.priviledgeOnId = priviledgeOnId;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code of entity class that is being duplicated? Do you use `GraphRepository`?

Comment: @MarekJeszka yes i am using GraphRepository,

Comment: @MarekJeszka added entity class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a node in neo4j with one unique property other than ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263922/creating-a-node-in-neo4j-with-one-unique-property-other-than-id)

Answer (score 0):

As it can be found in the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996734/how-to-merge-instead-of-create-with-neo4jtemplate), to update (and not create new instance) you have to use an ID of the node, when invoking `save` method.

Alternatively (as found in the comments of mentioned question) you should create you own query based on this [documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-merge).

Comment: thank you for your revert , but i'as hoping some sort of code help